# MVC 5 keeps sending me to /Account/Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Despite adding OWIN authentication to my MVC site I keep getting redirected to `/Account/Login` even though I have set authentication to none in the web.config and changed the Owin LoginPath to `/Login/`

I have also noticed that the Startup.cs `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` never gets hit.....

I have added the following packages

```
Microsoft.Owin
Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Owin
Microsoft.Owin.Security
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Oauth
Owin
```

Do I need to configure OWIN to use my Startup.cs class or should it just work?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [OWIN Startup Class Detection](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection)

> Every OWIN Application has a startup class where you specify
>   components for the application pipeline. There are different ways you
>   can connect your startup class with the runtime, depending on the
>   hosting model you choose (OwinHost, IIS, and IIS-Express). The startup
>   class shown in this tutorial can be used in every hosting application.
>   You connect the startup class with the hosting runtime using one of
>   the these approaches:
>
> 1. **Naming Convention**: Katana looks for a class named `Startup` in namespace matching the assembly name or the global namespace.
> 2. **OwinStartup Attribute**: This is the approach most developers will take to specify the startup class. The following attribute will
>      set the startup class to the `TestStartup` class in the `StartupDemo`
>      namespace.
>
>    ```
>    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartupDemo.TestStartup))]
>    ```
>
>    The `OwinStartup` attribute overrides the naming convention. You can also specify a friendly name with this attribute, however, using a
>      friendly name requires you to also use the `appSetting` element in the
>      configuration file.

There are a few other things in addition to the above, which you will find at the link provided.